# More efficient way to handle user input data validation?

Tags: java, function, user-input

In Java, I have two while loops to validate user input and continuously prompt the user if they input the wrong data type. In this program, I only have 2 questions, but I can imagine a scenario where I have more than 10, at which point 10 while loops would be cumbersome code to read and maintain. Is there a more efficient way to check for errors while continuing to prompt the user? My initial thought is to package the while loop and error checks into a separate class function and call it when input is requested.

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class IncreaseAge {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validInput = true;
    String coolName = "Adam";
    int coolAge = 0;

    while(validInput){
        try{
            System.out.print("Hello, what is your first name? ");
            coolName = userInput.nextLine();
            validInput = false;
        }
        catch(Exception error){
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again!");
            userInput.next();
        }
    }
    validInput = true;
    while(validInput){
        try{
            System.out.print("Hi "+ coolName + "! How old are you?");
            coolAge = userInput.nextInt();
            validInput = false;
        }
        catch(Exception error){
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again!");
            userInput.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hello "+ coolName + ", in ten years you will be " + (coolAge+10));
    userInput.close();


}
```

}

Comment: As an aside, some time you should check out input validation is done in HTML 5. the "type" attribute on input limits the input to the kind of data you are looking for, and other attributes like "pattern" and "min/maxvalue" (for numerical inputs) provide a built in framework (that Java lacks) for dealing with user input.

Comment: Your use of the word 'valid' is odd.  You have coded this as validInput being true when the input is **not** valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `private int getIntegerInput(String prompt)` and `private String getStringInput(String prompt)`, each of which will more or less be the same as the two loops you've already coded.

This is a common and frequent way to avoid code repetition - implement "helper" routines to be used in writing your intended functionality.

Even if you don't have repetition to worry about, it's a useful partitioning of code, making it easier to understand - for example, the "get an input" code is clearly distinct from the "process the input" code.

---

Example:

```
private String getStringInput(Scanner scanner, String prompt) {
    String input = null;
    boolean validInput = false;
    while (!validInput) {
       try {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            validInput = !input.isEmpty();
        }
        catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again!");
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Note that I fixed the use of 'validInput' to make sense, and I assume you want to reprompt on an empty input line.

Usage is then like

```
String coolName = getStringInput(userInput, "What is your first name? ");
```